# Order of growth proofs?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I was wondering how people go about showing the proofs with orders of growth? Currently, I have the following functions and I know what order they go in, but I'm not sure how to prove them. I simply put them into a graphing application I saw online and the graph itself obviously showed the growth.

$$\begin{align}
& 2^{\sqrt{\log n}}\\
& 2^n\\
& n^{4/3}\\
& n  \log^3 n\\
& n^{ \log n}\\
& 2^{2^n}\\
& 2^{n^2}
\end{align}$$

For example, I know that $2^{2^n}$ has the largest growth rate, with $2^{n^2}$ coming in second. I know this because if I plug the value of $5$ it turns into $2^{32}$ vs $2^{25}$, $6$ is $2^{64}$ vs $2^{36}$. But, is that the proof itself?

As far as the odd ones out, I have no idea how I could show a proof comparison of $n^{4/3}$ vs $n\log^3 $n vs $2^n$, etc.

Comment: In general, this is a difficult problem.  However, for your specific case, it is relatively tractable.  "$f(n) << g(n)$" is equivalent to "$lg f(n) << lg g(n)$" for your examples.  And a constant grows slower that $lg n$, which grows slower than $n^k$, which grows slower than $2^n$.

Comment: So, it's basically about identifying which ones are constants vs which ones are lg(n) vs which ones are n^k vs 2^n?

Comment: Also, are you sure that a constant grows slower than lg(n)? It seems that lg(n) grows far slower...

Comment: A constant function $f(n)=c$ doesn't grow at all, so I'm not sure why you think that it grows slower than a logarithmic function $g(n)=\log n$.

Comment: @Chris: Oh, i was trying to compare n^(4/3) vs n^(lg(n)) ... they both are n^k which i figure then I compare 4/3 to lg(n). Or, is that totally off?

Comment: @Chris: Oh, and 2^sqrt(lg(n)) seems to be the slowest growing one, yet it's a 2^n item (an adjusted n)?

Comment: Ok, it was just a misunderstanding then. When Craig and I said `a constant grows slower than $\log n$' we meant that a constant function grows slower than a logarithmic function. What Craig pointed out is that saying $f(n)\ll g(n)$ is equivalent to saying $\log f(n)\ll \log g(n)$ (since $\log$) is a monotonic increasing function) and so you can compare the growth rates of $n^c$ and $n^\log n$ by comparing the growth rates of $c$ and $\log n$, as you seem to be doing.

Comment: Notice that $n^{4/3} = (e^{4/3})^{\log n}$ which allows you to compare the growth rate with $2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ by taking logs.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor, I'm not *as* lost, but still a bit. I guess I know the order, but the whole part of showing a proof to it outside of just plugging in values gets me. And, the mixed bag of types makes it harder as well. If it were just 2^n vs 2^n^2 vs 2^lg(n) that would be easy...

Answer (score 4):

General Rules of Thumb which hold for sufficiently large $n$:

$$\begin{align}
&\log^c(n) \leq n^{\epsilon}, \quad \text{ for any } \epsilon > 0, \quad \text { and any constant } c
\\

\\
&n^k \leq k^n, \qquad \text{where } k \text{ is any constant } k > 1
\end{align}
$$

As Chris noted above, we can write this as

$$
A \ll \log^c (n) \ll n^{\epsilon} \ll k^n
$$

To actually prove these rules, you just compute limits (assuming you know calculus).  To see that $\log (n) \ll n^{\varepsilon}$ for example, just note that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n^{\epsilon}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{-1}}{\epsilon n^{\epsilon - 1}} = 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\epsilon n^{\epsilon}} = 0.
$$

where $A$ and $c$ are constants, $\epsilon > 0$, and $k$ is a real number such that $k > 1$.

If you want to show that $\log^c(n) \ll n^{\epsilon}$ for any positive integer $c$, then just note that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log^c (n)}{n^\epsilon} \leq \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log (n)}{n^{\epsilon/c}} \right) \dots \left( \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\log(n)}{n^{\epsilon/ c}}\right) = 0
$$
by what we showed above.  We can actually take $c$ be to be any arbitrary real number and the above still holds.  This is easy to see since every real number is less than or equal to some integer (infinitely many in fact!).  I will leave it to you to show that $n \log^3 (n) \ll n^{4/3}$, for example.  The more complicated functions work the same way but we might need to be slightly creative when evaluating the limits.

Hope this helps.